# Wine mono is not installed

Tags: kubuntu, wine, mono

I'm encountering an issue ive seen questions about, however none of the solutions actually work for me. Someone said to open an uninstaller msi(?) to install, however i cant open msi files on linux so i have no idea what i have to do.
I have used winetricks to install dotnet 45 however no solutions seem to work?
The error is:

```
0128:err:mscoree:CLRRuntimeInfo_GetRuntimeHost Wine Mono is not installed
```

and i used this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Comment: As written, the information you have provided is unclear. For example: *"an issue ive seen questions about"* | *"none of the solutions actually work*" | "*msi files*" -- We have no way of knowing what you're talking about here. A good start would be to tell us what software you're trying to install. Tell us what version of Ubuntu you're using.  Share your research. Include links. When providing errors, give the whole error, and we also need to know the steps needed to reproduce the error. Please edit your question.Don't make us guess at any details or your question may be impossible to answer.